# Correlating varchar values

Tags: sql, oracle, statistics

Is there a built-in way in Oracle 11 to check correlation of values in a varchar2 field?  For example, given a simple table such as this:

```
MEAL_NUM  INGREDIENT
--------------------
1         BEEF
1         CHEESE
1         PASTA
2         CHEESE
2         PASTA
2         FISH
3         CHEESE
3         CHICKEN
```

I want to get a numerical indication that based on MEAL_NUM, CHEESE is paired mostly with PASTA and to lessening degrees with BEEF, CHICKEN, and FISH.

My first inclination is to use the CORR function and transform the strings into a number perhaps by either enumerating them beforehand or grabbing the rownum from a unique select.

Any suggestions how to go about this?

Answer (score 3):

You won't want to use `CORR` -- if you create a "food number" and assign Beef = 1, Chicken = 2, and Pasta = 3, then a correlation coefficient will tell you whether increased cheese correlates with increased "food number." But the "food number" being higher or lower doesn't mean anything since you made it up. So, don't use `CORR` unless your foods are actually ordered in some way, like numbers are.

The way statisticians talk about this is with [levels of measurement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levels_of_measurement). In the language of the linked article, `MEAL_NUM` is a nominal measure -- or maybe an ordinal measure if the meals happened in order, but either way, it's a really bad idea to use correlation coefficients on it.

You'll probably instead want to find something like "what percentage of Beef meals also have Cheese?" The following will return, for each ingredient, the number of meals containing it and also the number of meals containing it AND cheese. The trick is that `COUNT` only counts non-null values.

```
SELECT Other.Ingredient, 
       COUNT(*) AS TotalMeals, 
       COUNT(Cheese.Ingredient) AS CheesyMeals
     FROM table Other
LEFT JOIN table Cheese
      ON (Cheese.Ingredient = 'Cheese' 
      AND Cheese.Meal_Num = Other.Meal_Num)
GROUP BY Other.Ingredient
```

Warning: returns wrong results if you include an ingredient twice in any one meal.

Edit: It turns out you aren't interested in Cheese specifically. You really want all the pairs of "correlations." So, we can abstract "Cheese" out and call them just the First and Second ingredients. I've added a "PossibleScore" to this one which tries to act like a percentage-of-meals but doesn't give a strong score if there are very few instances of the ingredient.

```
SELECT First.Ingredient, 
       Second.Ingredient, 
       COUNT(*) AS MealsWithFirst, 
       COUNT(First.Ingredient) AS MealsWithBoth,
       COUNT(First.Ingredient) / (COUNT(*) + 3) AS PossibleScore,
     FROM table First
LEFT JOIN table Second
      ON (First.Meal_Num = Second.Meal_Num)
GROUP BY First.Ingredient, Second.Ingredient
```

When sorted by score, this should return

```
PASTA    CHEESE    2    2    0.400
CHEESE   PASTA     3    2    0.333
BEEF     CHEESE    1    1    0.250
BEEF     PASTA     1    1    0.250
FISH     CHEESE    1    1    0.250
FISH     PASTA     1    1    0.250
CHICKEN  CHEESE    1    1    0.250
PASTA    BEEF      2    1    0.200
PASTA    FISH      2    1    0.200
CHEESE   BEEF      3    1    0.167
CHEESE   FISH      3    1    0.167
CHEESE   CHICKEN   3    1    0.167
```

Comment: This is really good information. I think the reason the OP wanted to use a function like corr() is so he could apply it to the whole data set rather than just one ingredient.

Comment: @James Oh; that's a very good point actually. It would be an interesting exercise to generalize my "Cheese" table so that it isn't necessarily called "Cheese," but I'll wait to hear from the OP.

Comment: Yes, I plan to let this thing run on the whole dataset.

Comment: @owook I abstracted out the cheese; the last query should give you something that you can use whatever statistical method you want on. I gave a simple scoring mechanism, but you should use whatever works best for you. A good read might be [this blog post](http://blog.reddit.com/2009/10/reddits-new-comment-sorting-system.html) while you are thinking about how to rank the pairs.

Answer (score 2):

Do a self join to get all the in ingredient combinations, then corr by the two meal_nums

```
SELECT t1.INGREDIENT, t2.INGREDIENT, CORR(t1.MEAL_NUM, t2.MEAL_NUM)
FROM TheTable t1, TheTable t2
WHERE t1.INGREDIENT < t2.INGREDIENT
GROUP BY t1.INGREDIENT, t2.INGREDIENT
```

Should give you something like:

```
BEEF    CHEESE  0.999
BEEF    PASTA   0.998
CHEESE  PASTA   0.977
```

UPDATE: as Chris points out, this won't work as is. What I was hoping is that there might be some way to fudge a mapping from the **ordinal** meal_num to an **interval** (@Chris, thanks for the link) value. That may not be possible, in which case this answer wouldn't help.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is a bad idea; if beef appears in meals 2, 3, 4 and cheese appears only in meal 6 then you will be finding the correlation coefficient with pairs (2,6), (3,6), and (4,6). That will be a problem -- the points all lie on a horizontal line, and the correlation coefficient will return something very interesting there.

Comment: Update: It's not just false positives -- my stats is a little rusty, but I think the correlation coefficient should return a divide by zero error if you give it my example data. If you give `CORR` anything that is not actually a numerical measure, you are asking for all kinds of trouble.

Comment: [Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levels_of_measurement) is a more technical discussion of what I was trying to say with the words "numerical measure."

Comment: Sorry for belaboring the point, but `MEAL_NUM` just doesn't have any interval meaning, so applying certain statistics to it will just return nonsense. The way to fudge it might be to replace `MEAL_NUM` with `MEAL_datetime`. **Then** `CORR` would give us something -- not necessarily what the OP wants, but definitely something. So, in my opinion, your answer is useful, and I'm giving it +1 even though I am sure it is wrong. :)

Comment: I think there's some potential to this approach - the actual dataset is large enough where I wouldn't have to worry about the situation you mention in your first comment.  The lack of significance to MEAL_NUM is definitely something I'm wrestling with - I need to relate the INGREDIENTs through it, but otherwise it's just an ID.  The end goal is to discover relationships that are more common than chance, yet unexpected (in this example assume a large number of meals were produced by monkeys at typewriters)

Answer (score 1):

Try [DBMS_FREQUENT_ITEMSET](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e16760/d_frqist.htm#BHAHCCDB):

```
--Create sample data
create table meals(meal_num number, ingredient varchar2(10));

insert into meals
select 1, 'BEEF' from dual union all
select 1, 'CHEESE' from dual union all
select 1, 'PASTA' from dual union all
select 2, 'CHEESE' from dual union all
select 2, 'PASTA' from dual union all
select 2, 'FISH' from dual union all
select 3, 'CHEESE' from dual union all
select 3, 'CHICKEN' from dual;

commit;

--Create nested table type to hold results
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE fi_varchar_nt AS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(10);
/

--Find the items most frequently combined with CHEESE.
select bt.setid, nt.column_value, support occurances_of_itemset
    ,length, total_tranx
from
(
    select
        cast(itemset as fi_varchar_nt) itemset, rownum setid
        ,support, length, total_tranx
    from table(dbms_frequent_itemset.fi_transactional(
        tranx_cursor => cursor(select meal_num, ingredient from meals),
        support_threshold => 0,
        itemset_length_min => 2,
        itemset_length_max => 2,
        including_items => cursor(select 'CHEESE' from dual),
        excluding_items => null))
) bt,
table(bt.itemset) nt
where column_value <> 'CHEESE'
order by 3 desc;


     SETID COLUMN_VAL OCCURANCES_OF_ITEMSET     LENGTH TOTAL_TRANX
---------- ---------- --------------------- ---------- -----------
         4 PASTA                          2          2           3
         3 FISH                           1          2           3
         1 BEEF                           1          2           3
         2 CHICKEN                        1          2           3
```

Answer (score 0):

what about a query like that?

```
select t1.INGREDIENT, count(*)a 
from table t1,
     (select meal_num 
      from table 
      where INGREDIENT = 'CHEESE') t2
where t1.INGREDIENT <> 'CHEESE'
and t1.meal_num=t2.mealnum
group by t1.INGREDIENT;
```

the result should be the number of time each ingredient share a meal_num with CHEESE.